# What is "the pose" Eren did in chapter 89?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Please do not spoil yourself the content of this masterpiece.

> In chapter 89, the first pages, Hanji says that Eren is doing "the pose"? What does she mean? Is that the same pose that Zeke (beast titan) does or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the meaning of this, after reading the next manga chapters.

If you are not up to date with the manga, please do not read below.

> The 'pose' Eren made is the posture of the Attack Titan, one of the 9 original Titans. Eren is lost in this time-crossing memory line of all the previous Attack Titan vessels. His memories sometimes are corrupted by interfering with the memory-line of the Attack Titan former vessels, and this pose is a signature posture of the Attack Titan.

Answer (score 1):

> The pose is called Shingeki no Kyojin as Hange said. Every 9 "special" titans have their own pose for example Colossal Titan, Bertholdt, Armored Titan, Reiner and Female Titan, Annie.